# Matlab lsqnonlin() with function handle as argument inside the loss/cost function

Tags: matlab, optimization, anonymous-function, curve-fitting, symbolic-math

I am trying to use the lsqnonlin() function together with the symbolic math toolbox. Specifically, I try to do the following:

```
global func
func = GetMyFunc();

options = optimset('Disp','iter','UseParallel',true,'TolFun',1e-8,'FinDiffType','central');
[x,resnorm,unused,exitflag] = lsqnonlin(@(x) LossFunction(x,data1,data2,data3,data4),x0,lb,ub,options);
```

LossFunction() is defined in a separate .m file as

```
function LossFunction(x,data1,data2,data3,data4)
global func
w = 1./data4;
LF = w.*(data1 - func(data2,data3,x(1),x(2),x(3),x(4),x(5)));
end
```

GetMyFunc is also defined in a separate .m file:

```
function MyHandle = GetMyFunc()
syms x y z 
AA = x.*y + z.^6.*y.^12;
BB = x.^4 - y.*x*z;
CC = diff(BB,x);
DD = diff(AA,z) + diff(AA,y);
EE = matlabFunction(CC);
FF = matlabFunction(DD);
MyHandle = @(x,y,z) double(EE(x,y,z) + FF(x,y,z));
end
```

data1, data2, data3, and data4 are large (about (80000x1)) vectors.
The problem I'm having is that Matlab freezes as soon as the lsqnonlin() is called. I already tried to pass func as an additional argument to LossFunction() instead of defining it as global. However, Matlab still seems to freeze.
If I save (a simplified) func in an .m file everything works just fine, the problem only appears if I try to use function handles.

The above expressions are simplified. My actual func is a very large function and for what I want to do it is not a possibility to save func to a .m file.
(I tried this but func seems to be too large for that).

I assume that the problem is that func is quite huge and so the evaluation takes extremely long
Has anyone an idea how to do that efficiently/increase the performance? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you made sure you can evaluate LossFunction(x) for typical values such as x0? Since func is generated code, is this a simple symbolic derivative or something you could also compute numerically as an alternative?

Comment: Theoretically I could also approximate it numerically. However, for the specific application I have in mind I need the symbolic derivatives. I can evaluate LossFunction() but it takes very long. The problem seems to be the evaluation of the function handle which is generated by GetMyFunc(). Is there any way to speed this evaluation up?